# macro form of clojure.core apply function

Tags: performance, clojure, macros, apply

in `clojure.core` there is the `apply` function, written in a multiple arity style (presumably for efficiency).

However I ask whether an implementation like thus:

`(defmacro apply [f coll] (conj (seq coll) f))`

would not be better.

I am aware of the fact that a macro is less efficient than a function,
but does it really make such a difference?

And alternatively, is it not possible to write this macro as a function
(I've tried but failed, but that's no proof as I have nil experience writing macros)?

Comment: If something can be expressed as function or a macro, we tend to prefer expressing it as a function. One reason is that functions are values (and macros are not). `clojure.core/apply` can be partially applied, for instance. Your 'apply' macro is clever, but doing something with a macro that can be done with a function is almost always a mistake. We need macros because not everything can be expressed as a function, this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @Harold Worse than that: `apply` can be written as a function but it can't be written as a macro (unless that macro just delegates to `apply` anyway). The "clever" implementation doesn't actually do anything useful. I was sure this ground had been covered somewhere on Stack Overflow and I could just close this as a duplicate, but I can't find it anywhere so I guess I'm writing an answer.

Comment: The "clever" version does expand into a list with the `f` first followed by the elements of `coll`, which if you're extremely lucky can evaluate to the same value as just calling `apply`. However, my gut is telling me that some values of `coll` aren't going to behave the way we want. Looking forward to your answer. (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason `apply` is a function instead of a macro is that it has to be. The macro version you've defined is useless: it doesn't work.

But why not? It seems like a reasonable idea. Let's try it out, but call it `mapply` so we can still refer to the existing `apply`:

```
=> (defmacro mapply [f coll] (conj (seq coll) f))
```

I bet you did this, and I bet you even tested it: you *can* use `mapply` in the absolute simplest of cases, like so:

```
=> (macroexpand '(mapply + [1 2 3]))
(+ 1 2 3) 
=> (mapply + [1 2 3])
6
```

The problem is that this isn't useful: you wrote `(mapply + [1 2 3])`, but it would have been just as easy (easier, really) to write `(+ 1 2 3)` instead. So this use case is not evidence that `mapply` is useful. When else would an `apply`-like macro be useful?

The real value of `apply` is that you can apply it to lists determined at runtime: when the argument list is fixed at compile time, you don't need `apply` because you could just write `(f x y)` instead of `(apply f [x y])`.

So let's try your version on a list computed at runtime:

```
=> (apply + (range 4))
6
=> (macroexpand '(mapply + (range 4)))
(+ range 4)
=> (mapply + (range 4))
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval2051 (REPL:1).
clojure.core$range cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

What happened? Your `mapply` saw that `(range 4)` was a collection, so it put `+` at the front of it. What you *wanted* was to evaluate `(range 4)`, yielding a list, and then add its elements somehow. But because `mapply` works at compile time, the list it sees is `(range 4)`: a two-element list containing the elements `range` and 4.

And this isn't just some simple bug in your `mapply` definition: it's impossible to define `mapply` as a macro (except as a trivial one that does no work at compile time and delegates to `apply` at runtime). For a more clearly-impossible example, consider calling your `mapply` from inside a function:

```
=> (defn sum [xs] (apply + xs))
=> (sum (range 4))
6
=> (defn msum [xs] (mapply + xs))
Syntax error macroexpanding mapply at (REPL:1:17).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Since `mapply` is a macro, it of course runs *at compile time*, i.e. at the time we are defining `msum`. It only gets one chance to expand, without knowing what `xs` we might pass it in the future. So when it looks at `xs`, it sees simply the symbol `xs`, not some list. As a result the `seq` call inevitably fails. And again, no other implementation would work, because you simply don't know at compile time how many elements the list has, and can't expand to the right call.

As a final treat, consider another reason `apply` couldn't be a macro: you can apply a function to an infinite list of arguments, but if you try to generate an infinitely long macro expansion the compiler will have a very sad time.

```
=> (defn apply-to-nats [f] (apply f (range)))
=> (apply-to-nats (fn [& args] (first args)))
0
=> (defmacro mapply-to-nats [f] (cons f (range)))
=> (mapply-to-nats (fn [& args] (first args)))
Syntax error (OutOfMemoryError) compiling at (REPL:1:1).
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

What happened? The compiler ran in a loop until my system ran out of memory, trying to compile

```
((fn [& args] (first args)) 0 1 2 3 4 ...)
```

Comment: Very good answer. However, is it not possible to somehow cause the macro to evaluate the list at runtime? And as regards infinite seqs I should think that `partial` would solve that, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ShmuelGreenberger I wouldn't have said "No, this is impossible, and here's why" multiple times in my answer if I meant "Actually you can totally do that with this one simple trick".